# (8.0/9.0/Master) Is there a way to implement Redis as a caching mechanism for Odoo 8?

Tags: redis, odoo, odoo-8, redis-cache

I'm interested in using Redis cache as a cache for product images among other things in Odoo 8.

I'd like to cache images for use on the frontend (ie. website_sale product pages and category pages), as well as on the backend (eg. Sale >> Product > Product Name > Images).

Is anyone aware of a project that has implemented Redis for caching within Odoo, or has any suggestions for where to start if there isn't anything out there already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@user3473233,

You should have a look at this documentation ["High availability OpenERP"](http://www.scribd.com/doc/116781163/High-Availability-Opener-p) and interesting [answer here](https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/openerp-in-a-high-availability-cloud-environment-2447)

Comment: Thanks for the link, that's very useful. I've responded on the Odoo forum post to Axel Mendoza's comment.